# Shallow copy of object attribute

Tags: python

I would like to make a temporary copy of an object attribute, such that I can manipulate it without affecting the object attribute. I've tried several ways of doing so but I'm not sure why it is not working. The object attribute concerned here is `sc.theta`, which is a 3-dimensional list of integers. `sc` is an instance of a custom class `Scenario`. (A MWE is included at the end of this question).

These are the several ways I've tried but they seem to be "deep copies" instead.

1. Making a copy of the 3D list

   ```
   theta_clone = sc.theta
   theta_clone[0][0][0] = 100

   assert theta_clone[0][0][0] == sc.theta[0][0][0]
   ```
2. Making a "shallow" copy of the list using `copy.copy()`

   ```
   theta_clone = copy.copy(sc.theta)
   theta_clone[0][0][0] = 100

   assert theta_clone[0][0][0] = sc.theta[0][0][0]
   ```
3. Making a "shallow" copy of the entire object using `copy.copy()`

   ```
   sc_clone = copy.copy(sc.theta)
   sc_clone.theta[0][0][0] = 100

   assert sc_clone.theta[0][0][0] == sc.theta[0][0][0]
   ```

You can reproduce this by using the following MWE:

```
from copy import copy

class Scenario:
    def __init__(self):
        self.theta = [[[4, 5, 6, 5, 4], [4, 5, 6, 5, 4], [4, 5, 6, 5, 4]]]

sc = Scenario()

# Method 1
theta_clone = sc.theta
theta_clone[0][0][0] = 100

assert theta_clone[0][0][0] == sc.theta[0][0][0]

# Method 2
theta_clone = copy(sc.theta)
theta_clone[0][0][0] = 100

assert theta_clone[0][0][0] == sc.theta[0][0][0]

# Method 3
sc_clone = copy(sc)
sc_clone.theta[0][0][0] = 100

assert sc_clone.theta[0][0][0] == sc.theta[0][0][0]
```

Comment: When you say property, do you mean attribute? Both words have very specific, not entirely interchangeable meanings, in Python.

Comment: Are you sure you know what "deep copy" means? Your inability to find the correct solution likely stems from a misunderstanding there.

Comment: Also, when you say `self.sc = [[[4, 5...`, did you mean `self.theta = [[[4, 5...`?

Comment: For each case, can you explain what you would expect to see vs. what you actually see? I am really not sure what your question is, besides a vague feeling that you don't understand something.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the differences and yes I’m actually referring to attributes, not properties. I’ve made the changes in the edits. Same goes to `self.sc`, it should be `self.theta`. I expect to get a copy of theta where I can change its values without changing the attribute in the object. I expect to see exceptions with each of the assertions.

Comment: Precise terminology is important. Particularly in this case, where yours is completely off.

Comment: Do you understand how object references work? Perhaps pointers in C?

Comment: ...you're making shallow copies, so you're changing sc each time.  Even if you weren't, the first method is changing sc.theta so the asserts after that wouldn't fail even with a deepcopy.

Comment: Oh god, I think I misunderstood deep and shallow copy. Thanks for pointing that out. I’ll edit the question. I’m not sure why the first one doesn’t work though.

Comment: it doesn't work because it's a shallow copy, which means it's a reference to the original object, not a copy at all.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I understand how object references work, I just messed up between shallow vs deep copy. Oh god I feel so stupid. Thanks!